# ListView is not populating

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I created an Adapter to populate my custom listView and when ran on the emulator the activity is blank.  Plz help.  I am sure I'm missing something 'cause I am new to java & Android. Some code snippets to correct it and pointers will be appreciated. Thnx!

My Activity:

```
public class List_AC3 extends ListActivity {

/**
 * -- Called when the activity is first created
 * ===================================================================
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_view2);

    displayResultList();
}

private void displayResultList() {
    Cursor databaseCursor = null;
    DomainAdapter databaseListAdapter = new DomainAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, databaseCursor, 
            new String[] {"label", "title", "description"}, 
            new int[] { R.id.label, R.id.listTitle, R.id.caption });
            databaseListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            setListAdapter(databaseListAdapter);
}
}
```

My Adapter:

```
public class DomainAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
String extStorageDirectory;

public DomainAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from,
        int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
        holder.text3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.caption);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File dbfile = new File(extStorageDirectory+ "/Aero-Technologies/flyDroid/dB/flyDroid.db");
    SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbfile, null);
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM AC_list", null);

    data.moveToPosition(position);

    int label_index = data.getColumnIndex("label"); 
    String label = data.getString(label_index);

    int title_index = data.getColumnIndex("title"); 
    String title = data.getString(title_index);

    int description_index = data.getColumnIndex("description"); 
    String description = data.getString(description_index);

    holder.text1.setText(label);
    holder.text2.setText(title);
    holder.text3.setText(description);

    return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView text1;
        TextView text2;
        TextView text3;
    }  
}
```

The list_view2.xml:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dip" 
    android:padding="4dip"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/homeBtn"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@null" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleBarTitle"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/toolBtn"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@null" />

</RelativeLayout>

<ListView 
   android:id="@id/android:list" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And my list_item.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/acItem"
style="@style/listItem" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    style="@style/listAcronym" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/listTitle"
    style="@style/listTitle" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/caption"
    style="@style/listDiscription"/>        

<ImageView
    style="@style/listNextIcon" />   

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your call to setContentView is commented out, why is that? Could it be you need to uncomment that....? Also, it would be helpful if you posted the XML for the layout.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to uncomment that when I was trying to find my issue.  I'll post the XML files.  Thnx!  @debracey

Comment: Also, I know I have an issue w/ private void displayResultList() {
  Cursor databaseCursor = null;  <---- I'm not sure how to do this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer can be found [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5834102/600984) along with the code.

Answer (score 1):

the [google notepad tutorials](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html) should also help you IIRC they should be using cursors passed to a listview

Answer (score 0):

SimpleCursorAdapter doesn't need to be extended to work.  Take your db logic out of getView and use it to construct a cursor which actually points to a db result.  Then pass that cursor to the SimpleCursorAdapter constructor.  In fact, I don't think getView is actually being called anywhere.

Try getting this example working http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/ first and then edit it to do what you need.

If you want to do something more complex (like setting the various textviews yourself like you're trying to do in getView) look into CursorAdapter.